# I want a script or widget to display a random line of text over top my desktop background every X minutes

Tags: bash

I ahve a multi monitor setup, and I am looking for a script to display a random line of text from a file (like an inspirational quote) either as a notification, or overlayed over my desktop background.  How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure where the multi-monitor jumps in?

Comment: `Conky` is very powerful tool for doing such things, but is not the easiest solution ;-)

Comment: Hi Paul, isn't too difficult, but did you see my question? Where does the multimonitor jump in?

Comment: Hi @JacobVlijm, thanks for your comments - I mentioned mult-monitor because I have tried out about 3 different wallpaper switchers etc, and all of them have issues with multi monitor setup.  If possible I would like to be able to specify which monitor I want the text on, and / or also place it on all monitors

Comment: On both similarly is quite easy,  on (only) either one of them is not impossible, but much more complicated. Would that be a requirement?

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your diligence.  If its too complicated to be able to specify a particular monitor, I am ok with monitor.  What I really want, is just to be able to display different phrases I have placed in a file throughout the day at certain intervals. Can you provide a script for this?